# np.int64 is a smaller container than np.int....?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting surprising behavior trying to convert a microsecond string date to an integer:

```
n = 20181231235959383171
int_ = np.int(n)  # Works
int64_ = np.int64(n)  # "OverflowError: int too big to convert"
```

Any idea why?

**Edit** - Thank you all, this is informative, however please see my actual problem:
[Dataframe column won't convert from integer string to an actual integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108913/dataframe-column-wont-convert-from-integer-string-to-an-actual-integer)

Comment: The first line `n = ... `  assigns a literal integer to `n` in ordinary python.  Those can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I need to put these large integers into a Numpy array. How do I do that

Comment: What do you get when you `print(int_)`? If it duplicates the input I'd say you are OK.

Comment: int_
Out[5]: 20181231235959383171

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `np.int` can be arbitrarily large, like a python integer.

An `np.int64` can only range from -2<sup>63</sup> to 2<sup>63</sup> - 1. Your number happens to fall outside this range.

Comment: Its a bit weird, because `np.int` does seem to have a different meaning in a context like `np.array([n]*10, dtype=np.int)`, which gives an overflow error as well. Also it seems that `np.int is int` is true.

Answer (score 3):

When used as `dtype`, `np.int` is equivalent to `np.int_` (architecture-dependent size), which is probably `np.int64`. So `np.array([n], dtype=np.int)` will fail. Outside `dtype`, `np.int` behaves as Python `int`. Numpy is basically helping you calculate as much stuff in C-land as possible in order to speed up the calculations and conserve memory; but (AFAIK) integers larger than 64 bits do not exist in standard C (though the new GCC does support them on some architectures). So you are stuck using either Python integers, slow but of unlimited size, or C integers, fast but not big enough for this.

There are two obvious ways to stuff a large integer into a numpy array:

- You can use the Python type, signified by `dtype=object`: `np.array([n], dtype=object)` will work, but you are getting no speedup or memory benefits from numpy.
- You can split the microsecond time into second time (`n // 1000000`) and second fractions (`n % 1000000`), as two separate columns.

Comment: if you post this answer to my related question I will accept it over there