# Dataframe column won't convert from integer string to an actual integer

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a date string in microsecond resolution. I need it as an integer.

```
import pandas as pd
data = ["20181231235959383171", "20181231235959383172"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["A"])
df["A"].astype(np.int)
```

Error:

```
File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 545, in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Same problem if I try to cast it to standard Python `int`

Comment: If this is datetime convert to datetime , rather than save it in int

Comment: no I receive it as a longer string which I have cut down to this

Comment: What the purpose convert to int ?

Comment: With a few delimiters, you can convert this string in to a `np.datetime64 array: `np.array("2018-12-31T23:59:59.383171": datetime64[us]')`

Comment: It can also be an object dtype array, containing Python `int` (as opposed to numpy `int64`): `np.array([int(i) for i in data], object)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58108900/240443) in your previous question:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ["20181231235959383171", "20181231235959383172"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["A"])

# slow but big enough
df["A_as_python_int"] = df["A"].apply(int)

# fast but has to be split to two integers
df["A_seconds"] = (df["A_as_python_int"] // 1000000).astype(np.int)
df["A_fractions"] = (df["A_as_python_int"] % 1000000).astype(np.int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = ["20181231235959383171", "20181231235959383172"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=["A"])

before = df.A[0]
df.A = [int(x) for x in df.A.tolist()]
after = df.A[0]
before, after
```

**Output**:
The data has been cast into an integer. Showing: `(before, after)`

```
('20181231235959383171', 20181231235959383171)
```